# MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook) - "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: excel, object, button, msgbox, vba

Good day.

This may be simple and all, but I would just like to know.
Within the first Sub of my Form, I placed at the very beginning of the code the following line:

```
MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook)
```

Such line would usually prompt the workbook active (as the call suggests).  When placed in other sections of the project, it surely works, but not here.  Instead, this error appears:

```
Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method
```

So, I'd just like to gain more understanding on the subject.  Thanks.

PS.  The sub I'm placing that line of code in is a simple button_Click().

Thanks again.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook` is an object but `MsgBox` want a string... try: `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to question the "Such line would usually prompt the workbook active (as the call suggests)" assertion.

`MsgBox` takes a `Variant` as an argument, but one that can be successfully cast to a `String` (`MsgBox$` is almost always better practice).

`ActiveWorkbook` returns a `Workbook` object, and a `Workbook` cannot be cast to a `String`.  I don't recall off the top of my head what the default property of `Workbook` is, but I know it isn't convertible into a `String`.  If you want to get the *name* of the `Workbook`, you need this:

```
MsgBox$ ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

You would need that anywhere, `Form`, `Class`, `Module`, ...anywhere.

Better practice would be to get a *reference* to the active `Workbook` and use that throughout your code.  See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4088852).

Comment: This is very well explained.  Thank you so much for the information.  Much appreciated.